# Finding a subspace with desired angles between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of vectors S in some high dimensional space V. I want to find a subspace B such that the cosine similarities of their projections in B are "close" to some fixed values. i.e.

$$
\forall v_i v_j \in S,  \frac{(Bv_i)\cdot(Bv_j)}{||Bv_i||||Bv_j||} \sim d_{ij}
$$

where the $d_{ij}$'s are fixed. Obviously I've left the definition of "close" vague. I'd be interested in any solution with a precise objective (e.g. minimize sum of square residuals) that is easy to implement.